# Skip to next line without loop

Tags: php, if-statement, continue

This function is typically called from within a loop but apparently the presence of continue causes an issue even when not actually using the function. It works fine on my more forgiving live server but my local development system protests. How do I tell it to continue to the next line without using continue?

```
function deleteImage($ImageName, $UpdateID) {
    $array = explode('.', $ImageName);
    $ext = end($array);

    if ($ext == "pdf") :
        $fileTemplate = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder1" . 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder2" . 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "%s";
    else :
        $fileTemplate = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder1" . 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder3" . 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "%s";
    endif;

    if (isset($_POST['update'])):
        if (!empty($_POST['CheckBox_Delete'][$UpdateID])) :
            $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM images WHERE ID=$UpdateID";
            $sqlFolder = "SELECT EntryID FROM images WHERE ID=$UpdateID";

            if (is_null($ImageName) || is_null($UpdateID)) continue;
            if (empty($ImageName) || empty($UpdateID)) continue;

            $fileName = sprintf($fileTemplate, $ImageName);
            DBConnect($sqlDelete, "Delete", "db_name");
            // Make sure the file is not in use elsewhere before deleting it from the server
            $sqlOtherUse = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM images WHERE ImageName='$ImageName' AND ID <> $UpdateID";
            $OtherUse = DBLookup($sqlOtherUse, "db_name");
            if ($OtherUse < 1) :
                @unlink($fileName);
                AlertMessage("The file has been deleted!");
            else:
                AlertMessage("Removed from this entry but the file is in use elsewhere so cannot be deleted.");
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Wait.. If you have a loop that calls this function, shouldn't you simply use `return` instead of `continue` in case you want the function to stop?

Comment: not exactly sure what you are intending, but `return` may work.

Comment: I'm not trying to stop the loop and really the loop isn't directly related to the question. Whether in a loop or not, I simply want to know how to move past a conditional without getting an error if the condition has been met. Return seems to work - or at least it doesn't give an error when just loading the site but I have tried to see what it does to the processing.

Comment: The `continue` statement has to be lexically inside the loop body, it can't be in a function that's called from the loop.

Comment: `return` doesn't stop the loop. If you call a function and you have some conditional if statement that should stop executing the function and continue to the next loop from that point on, you use `return`. It has the same effect as removing all the SQL parts from the function body if the if statements return true.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `continue` in a function that's called from the loop, it has to be in the actual loop code. What you can do is return a value from the function, and the caller can check this and then continue.

So change the caller to do this when it's part of a loop:

```
if (!deleteImage($imagename, $updateid) {
    continue;
}
```

Change all the `continue;` statements in the function to `return false;`, and put `return true;` at the end of the function.

```
function deleteImage($ImageName, $UpdateID) {
    $array = explode('.', $ImageName);
    $ext = end($array);

    if ($ext == "pdf") :
        $fileTemplate = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder1" . 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder2" . 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "%s";
    else :
        $fileTemplate = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder1" . 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "folder3" . 
                                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "%s";
    endif;

    if (isset($_POST['update'])):
        if (!empty($_POST['CheckBox_Delete'][$UpdateID])) :
            $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM images WHERE ID=$UpdateID";
            $sqlFolder = "SELECT EntryID FROM images WHERE ID=$UpdateID";

            if (is_null($ImageName) || is_null($UpdateID)) return false;
            if (empty($ImageName) || empty($UpdateID)) return false;

            $fileName = sprintf($fileTemplate, $ImageName);
            DBConnect($sqlDelete, "Delete", "db_name");
            // Make sure the file is not in use elsewhere before deleting it from the server
            $sqlOtherUse = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM images WHERE ImageName='$ImageName' AND ID <> $UpdateID";
            $OtherUse = DBLookup($sqlOtherUse, "db_name");
            if ($OtherUse < 1) :
                @unlink($fileName);
                AlertMessage("The file has been deleted!");
            else:
                AlertMessage("Removed from this entry but the file is in use elsewhere so cannot be deleted.");
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;
    return true;
}
```

BTW, there's no need to test both `is_null()` and `empty()`, since a null value is empty.

Comment: Perhaps using both is_null() and empty() is redundant and I wrote this function a long time ago and don't recall if I had a reason for doing it. You're right and now that I review it, it isn't necessary. The returns make sense so I'll give it a try too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just reverse some of the testing for the two `continue` lines and turn it into a code block?

```
if (!is_null($ImageName) && 
    !is_null($UpdateID) && 
    !empty($ImageName) && 
    !empty($UpdateID)) {

    // code continues here.

}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable so I'll give it a try. I was trying to make it a little cleaner by not wrapping it into the conditional but perhaps that's the best way. Thank you!